# How to add SVG to an application with wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, svg, wxwidgets

I'm new to C++ and I want to replace a PNG image in the GUI of my application with a SVG in wxWidgets 3.2.2.1. The part of my XML/XRC file containing information about the image has the following structure:

```
    <object class="wxStaticBitmap" name="testfile_1">
        <size>100, 100</size>
        <bitmap>testimage.png</bitmap>
    </object>
```

When I change my code to

```
    <object class="wxSVGFileDC" name="testfile_1">
        <size>100, 100</size>
        <bitmap>testimage.svg</bitmap>
    </object>
```

and compile my application and start it however, I always get an uninitialized sizer item error.

It looks like the sizer doesn't recognize my SVG. What should I do with my code or elsewhere so that my application successfully starts with the SVG? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to post the error message as text instead of an image.

Comment: @vekomp, you should have a panel/windowon which you put wxStaticBitmap with the SVG. Or just manually paint the SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why did you decide to use `wxSVGFileDC`, which is used for *creating* SVG files in your XRC (did ChatGPT advise this?), but if you look at [XRC documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/overview_xrcformat.html) you can easily see that it's not an allowed element there. And if you tried to [validate your XRC file](https://www.wxwidgets.org/blog/2015/04/validating-xrc/) you would have also found out that it doesn't pass the validation.

On the same XRC documentation page you can also read, in the ["Bitmap" section](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/overview_xrcformat.html#overview_xrcformat_type_bitmap) that to use SVG in your XRC file you simply need to write

```xml
        <bitmap default_size="32,32">testimage.svg</bitmap>
```